# MySQL/Laravel Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to run php artisan migrate to create my mysql tables usin laravel.

I got this error:
 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Users Table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('street');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

password_resets table:

```
Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
```

products table:

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('product_type');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Shipments table:

```
  Schema::create('shipments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('order_number')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('order_number')->references('id')->on('orders');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->dateTime('chargecardtime');
        $table->dateTime('packingtime');
        $table->date('shiporderdate');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Orders table:

```
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('to_street');
        $table->string('to_city');
        $table->date('ship_date');  
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Exception trace:

1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ec`.`#sql-3664_86` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

i guess there is a problem with orders table since after error i cant see that table in database.others are created.

Comment: Which of those statements do fail?

Comment: i cant see that

Comment: i guess there is a problem with orders table since after error i cant see that table in database.others are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're referencing an `id` you need to make the foreign key column `unsigned`. As ids are by default unsigned (non-negative).

So do this for all your foreign keys:

```
$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: Make sure that you really dropped all previously created fields and ran the migration on a fresh database.

Comment: Check in the database which table is the last created and which one should be next in your migration. That way you can easily tell which one fails. Make sure they're in order you posted them in

Answer (score 0):

you should add `unsigned()` method to your foreign keys columns, like `$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()` cause they must be exactly the same column types as the key that they are referenced. the referenced keys are probably unsigned integers, that's why you got the error. in MySQL, integer signed and integer unsigned are different types

Answer (score 0):

$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();

try this

$table->unsignedBigInteger(');